# if ((ret = func()) == -1)という書き方

Tags: c

C言語で関数の戻り値をチェックする方法で

```
if ((ret = func()) == -1)
```

という書き方があります。

これは

```
ret = func();
if (ret == -1)
```

と同じ意味なのですが、上記の書き方を検索して調べる時、どういうキーワードで調べればいいでしょうか? (Yoda notationなどのように、名前はあるのでしょうか？ )

また、上記の書き方は、MISRACやその他コーディング規約においては、許可されたものなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`if ((ret = func()) == -1)`との書き方は、一般的に「assignment in condition」、または「assignment in conditional expression」と呼ばれると思います。

ほとんどのコーディング規則に許可されません。（MISRA 2004ではルール13.1）

Comment: ありがとうございます。"assignment in condition"にて該当のものが検索できるようになりました。MISRACでの不許可の情報もありがとうございます。

Answer (score 8):

ご質問の回答になっていないかとは思いますが、私見としてご覧頂ければ幸いです。

if ((ret = func()) == -1)

の記述方法は、テストの際、デバッガでfunc()の戻り値を正確に把握するためのブレークポインタが打てないと思います。

昔、そうやって指導されましたので、今も多言語でもその教えを踏襲しています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。なるほど、ブレークポイントが打てずデバッグできなくなりますね。勉強になりました。

Answer (score 8):

上記の書き方に対する固有名詞は聞いたことがありません。
"assignment in conditional expression" とかで検索するしかなさそうな気がします。

一般論としては、比較演算子とのタイプミスだったりする可能性があるため、
避ける方が多い書き方かと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 "assignment in conditional expression" で検索できました。やはり避ける方がいいとのことですね。勉強になりました。

Answer (score 0):

I saw this expression before in some code.

As you know, the expression `if ((ret = func()) == -1)` is the same as

```
ret = func();
if (ret == -1)
```

but it is not a good recommendation for the C programmer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will use the latter one to avoid confusion by other people (including me after several months).

Comment: 討議中の英語の質問に対しての投票を促すためにお礼を設定しました。
荒っぽい方法ですが、メタまで目を通す人は少ないのでご理解いただければと思います。
ささやかですが、迷惑をお掛けしたお礼をさせていただきます。